# Grouped Histogram in Python

Tags: python, histogram

Is there a simple way of creating histograms for a continuous variable (mpg) that is filtered by a categorical variable (cyl=4,8)? So essentially I need two histograms for mpg grouped by cyl, one for cyl=4 and one for cyl=8.

[image]

Here is an example from a different dataset:
[image]

Comment: can you attach an example?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 

data = pd.DataFrame()
data[4] = np.random.normal(0,10,300)
data[8] = np.random.normal(20,11,300)

sns.distplot(data[4], color="skyblue")
sns.distplot(data[8], color="orange")
```

I just used my random sample.

I am just being a little lazy here, but all you need to do is a *seaborn* package.
There are much more options you can handle, so please read it more here [https://python-graph-gallery.com/]

[image]